# golang function alias on method receiver

Tags: go, alias

I can create method alias for an usual method:

```
func method1() {
    fmt.Println("method1")
}

var Method1 = method1
```

But cannot do the same for a method receiver:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func (p *Person) methodReciver() {
    fmt.Println("method reciver")
}

var MethodReciver = methodReciver
```

In this case I got the error on line `var MethodReciver = methodReciver`:

```
undefined: methodReciver
```

Full code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func method1() {
    fmt.Println("method1")
}

var Method1 = method1

func (p *Person) methodReceiver() {
    fmt.Println("method receiver")
}

var MethodReceiver = methodReceiver

func main() {
    method1()
    Method1()
    p := Person{"Nick"}
    p.methodReceiver()
    p.MethodReceiver()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nQeu-U08MQ)

Is it possible to create a method alias for `methodReceiver`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.  You can make an alias like this:

```
var MethodReceiver = (*Person).methodReceiver
```

When you call it, you have to provide a pointer to a person object as the first argument:

```
MethodReceiver(&p)
```

You can [see this in action on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/l-5Vu8bQ10).

Answer (score 36):

Basically you have 2 options:

#### 1. Using a [Method Expression](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions)

Which has the form of `ReceiverType.MethodName` and it yields a value of a function type:

```
var MethodReceiver = (*Person).methodReceiver
```

`MethodReceiver` just holds the function reference but *not* the receiver, so if you want to call it, you also have to pass a receiver (of type `*Person`) to it as its fist argument:

```
var p = &Person{"Alice"}
MethodReceiver(p)  // Receiver is explicit: p
```

#### 2. Using a [Method Value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values)

Which has the form of `x.MethodName` where the expression `x` has a static type `T`:

```
var p = &Person{"Bob"}
var MethodReceiver2 = p.methodReceiver
```

A method value also stores the *receiver* too, so when you call it, you don't have to pass a receiver to it:

```
MethodReceiver2()  // Receiver is implicit: p
```

#### Complete Example

Try it on [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/5AsTTuqU-z).

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func (p *Person) printName() {
    fmt.Println(p.Name)
}

var PrintName1 = (*Person).printName

func main() {
    var p1 *Person = &Person{"Bob"}
    PrintName1(p1) // Have to specify receiver explicitly: p1

    p2 := &Person{"Alice"}
    var PrintName2 = p2.printName // Method value, also stores p2
    PrintName2()                  // Implicit receiver: p2
}
```

Output:

```
Bob
Alice
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called [method expression](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) `var MethodReceiver = (*Person).methodReceiver`

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/l-5Vu8bQ10)